# How to declare array from listview1.listitems.count

Tags: vb.net, vb6

i am using following code to display chart records from Listview1

```
Dim X(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
 j = 1
 For i = 1 To Listview1.ListItems.Count
 X(j, 1) = Listview1.ListItems(i).Text
 X(j, 2) = Listview1.ListItems(i).SubItems(1)
 j = j + 1
 Next i

MSChart1.ChartData = X
MSChart1.chartType = 1
```

I need something like :

```
Dim X(1 To Listview1.listitems.count, 1 To 2) As Variant
```

it will help to add rows in mschart control

Comment: Do you get an error when you declare the array like that?  I'm not sure what the issue is.  Just as a side point I don't think you need the i either you could do it all using j.

Comment: Error while declaring as above : 'require constant'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dim` with an array requires the dimension argument to be constant (resolvable at compile time), you attempt to use a variable.

To use a variable, declare an undimensioned array:

```
Dim X() as variant
```

Then define its length with `ReDim`:

```
ReDim X(1 To Listview1.listitems.count, 1 To 2) '// no type
```

Or you can simply:

```
ReDim X(1 To Listview1.listitems.count, 1 To 2) as variant
```